Text between two characters
I'm trying with regular expression to select text between two () characters, complete with characters included.
EX. Text (the text) -> (the text)
EX2. Text text text (the text again) -> (the text again)
I'm very noob at this and only have ()(.*) and ((.*)) 
Thanks Mario

Almost got it: (?<=()(.*?)(?=))

To find ( or ) chars, you need to escape it :
\(.*\)
But leaving as is .* , it will also take the closing parenthesis and will not stop when found.
So you must search any number of chars except ^ closing parenthesis ):
[^)]*
Try this :  \([^)]*\)
